# Post form fields with Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a View in my MVC 3 application that lets the user enter the shipping address and place the order. The form fields that I show on the view are exactly the same as user profile fields. So I want to consider a link for the user to save the data they have entered into their profile too. Fields like first name, last name, address and so on.
I want to use Ajax.ActionLink, but the problem is I don't know how to send the form fields to the Action that saves the data. What I have is:

`@Ajax.ActionLink("Save into profile", "SaveAccountProfile", new{ address=????}, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess = "alert('Account profile was successfully updated.')" })`

What would I post as the route data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use an `Ajax.BeginForm` in this case. This way form field values will automatically be posted to the server.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveAccountProfile", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess = "alert('Account profile was successfully updated.')" }))
{
    ... some input fields
    <input type="submit" value="Save into profile" />   
}
```

Comment: The problem is the form is meant for the user to place an order. So there is already a button that submits the form. As I said, I am gonna consider a link or a button to post the same fields (textboxes) to save them as account profile too.

Comment: @user1137993, in this case I would recommend you using a standard Html.ActionLink that you would unobtrusively AJAXify using jQuery. You will have more control over the parameters sent to the server. The $.ajax metod allows you to pass any data to data server.

Comment: Thanks Darin. This seems to be the only way.